# How to add the parameter "/MT" in MSVC to a CMakeLists?

Tags: cmake

Doing my homework about CMake, I found a request," if you use MSVC,please add '/MT' in order to correctly link to the library" , followed by "if MGV, please add a link to library ws2_32".
I just don't know how to correctly write my CMakeLists, more precisely, how to write my options or use "if(cond) endif()" or something.

I found an article which exclaims:

```
MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>"
```

But I didn't understand it.